# Accessing a variable from outside the function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Javascript function and would like to retrieve the id value from outside the function. How can make "id" a static variable and access it from outside the function.

```
<input type="text" name="editinput" id="editinputtext" placeholder="Type Contribution...">
      <script>
          $(".contributions").click(function(){
          var id = this.id;
   });
document.getElementById("editinputtext").value = id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to declare variable outside of function.

```javascript
<script>
  var id;
  $(".contributions").click(function(){
     id = $(this).attr("id");
   });
  document.getElementById("editinputtext").value = id;
</script>
```

Comment: Note that `id` will be `undefined` here when it's assigned to `value` and it doesn't look like that's ever going to change…

Comment: When I run it, it says that the value is undefined, although I tried console.log and it returned the value of "id".

Comment: @Hadi Yes, because of *when* the `click` function executes. Why don't you assign to `editinputtext` ***inside*** the `click` function?!

Comment: That's because you're referring to "this.id" and it will have no value: try $(this).attr("id") instead.

Comment: I'll try that out right now and tell you the results. Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: Sorry. Answering for question about variable, didn't notice another code error. Fixed it.

Comment: Does it work now?  I'm waaaaaay too lazy to try it out myself :)

Comment: Also, if you have jQuery, why the document.getElementById?  You could just say $("#editinputtext").val(id)

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I did what you told me and found out a third party package is overriding.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do is simpler than you make it out to be. The variable `id` will not have any value and will be `undefined` until the actual click function is called.

So what you can do is define the variable within the click function and assign it straight to `editinputtext`. But you're also using jQuery so you can also assign it in this way.

```
<input type="text" name="editinput" id="editinputtext" placeholder="Type Contribution...">

<script>
   $(".contributions").click(function(){
      var id = this.id;
      $("#editinputtext").val(id);
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think I found the solution as a third party package I was using was causing the problem, after I removed it, I was able to access the value of id.